# Did Bill Ayers ghost-write for Obama?

Tags: politics, united-states, barack-obama

According to Conservapedia's article on [William Ayers](http://www.conservapedia.com/William_Ayers):

> In an October 2008 article in [American
>   Thinker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Thinker), **[Jack Cashill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Cashill) presented
>   evidence that Ayers [ghostwrote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostwriter) [Obama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obama)'s
>   first book, "[Dreams From My Father](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_of_My_Father)".**
>   He based his assertion on a comparison
>   of the writing styles of [Bill Ayers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Ayers)'
>   2001 memoir, [Fugitive Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugitive_Days), and Barack
>   Obama's earlier 1995 book, Dreams From
>   My Father, and came to the conclusion
>   that Ayres had ghostwritten Dreams.

In the Cashill article, [Who Wrote Dreams From My Father?](http://www.americanthinker.com/2008/10/who_wrote_dreams_from_my_fathe_1.html), Cashill states:

> As shall be seen, however, there are
>   only two real possibilities: one is
>   that Obama experienced a near
>   miraculous turnaround in his literary
>   abilities; **the second is that he had
>   major editorial help, up to and
>   including a ghostwriter**.

Cashill then goes on to list the reasons why he believes Bill Ayers, ghost-wrote "Dreams":

> I bought Bill Ayers' 2001 memoir,
>   Fugitive Days, for reasons unrelated
>   to this project.  As I discovered, he
>   writes surprisingly well and very much
>   like "Obama."  In fact, my first
>   thought was that the two may have
>   shared the same ghostwriter.  Unlike
>   Dreams, however, where the high style
>   is intermittent, Fugitive Days is
>   infused with the authorial voice in
>   every sentence. What is more, when
>   Ayers speaks, even off the cuff, he
>   uses a cadence and vocabulary
>   consistent with his memoir.  One does
>   not hear any of Dreams in Obama's
>   casual speech.

Cashill then goes on to list a myriad of ways he believes that Obama and Ayers are connected socially, politically, and ideologically.

But [Obama claims to barely know Bill Ayers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Ayers_presidential_election_controversy):

> This is a guy who lives in my
>   neighborhood, who's a professor of
>   English in Chicago who I know and who
>   I have not received some official
>   endorsement from. He's not somebody
>   who I exchange ideas from on a regular
>   basis.

It would seem implied from this statement that Obama has not sought a close relationship with Ayers and thus it is unlikely that he ghost-wrote Obama's book.

**Is there any truth or evidence to support Cashill's claim that Obama's book "[Dreams From My Father](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1400082773)" was written by Bill Ayers?**

[image]

Comment: I misread the title at first and thought you were asking if a ghost wrote a book... Doh ;)

Comment: Asking any question out of "conservipedia" is like asking if the BigFootForums is an impartial source on cryptids...  The site is a haven for outright lies and denial of reality (they want to redact the theory of relativity because it's too liberal FFS!).

Comment: @Brightblades And they can't even decide if the theory of relativity is wrong (as in, not true) or bad (as in, helped develop the nuclear bomb).

Comment: Ayer's book was pusblished after Obama's, so why not assume Ayer copied Obama?

Comment: @Lagerbear, I know what you mean!  They give "cranks" a bad name even...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is certainly no hard evidence that Bill Ayers had anything to do with the writing of **Dreams from My Father**. There isn't much indirect evidence either, unless you agree with Cashill's frankly puerile literary analysis. (One of his arguments it that [only former sailors will write about the wind or use ships as metaphors](http://www.americanthinker.com/2008/10/who_wrote_dreams_from_my_fathe_1.html).) There's no way to prove conclusively Ayers didn't work on the book either, but we must test the credibility of the claim based on the evidence there is, not on what some people might want to be true.

A few other elements that should probably be considered.

- **Timing.** No one, including Cashill, is claiming Ayers and Obama
  knew each other in any capacity
  before 1995, and the book came out in
  July of that year. While it's not
  impossible to produce a book that
  quickly, it would have probably kept
  the two from doing much else during
  that time.
- **Motive.** In early 1995, when Ayers and Obama would have supposedly been
  working on the book together, [Obama
  had not yet made his first step into
  even local politics](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/10/04/us/politics/04ayers.html?pagewanted=2). So unless
  Ayers or Obama somehow knew that
  thirty years later Obama would be
  running for a federal office where
  his relationship with a local
  professor could become a major
  campaign issue, there's no good
  reason Ayers wouldn't have just been
  given a co-author credit.
- **Cashill's credibility.** Cashill has made a cottage industry out of
  [doubting every single detail about
  Barak Obama's biography](http://mediamatters.org/blog/201102240030), always
  on the flimsiest evidence. Just a
  couple weeks ago he published a
  [column on WorldNetDaily](http://www.wnd.com/index.php?fa=PAGE.view&pageId=283881) claiming
  to have found proof that Barak Obama
  was photoshopped into photos taken of
  him with his grandparents in New York
  City. The claim was so ridiculous
  that even WorldNetDaily scrubbed the
  photo claim from the column after a
  couple days, but you can see the
  photos Cashill was using [here](http://mediamatters.org/blog/201104070013)
  and hear him talking about his
  discovery in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA7hd3j1yHI&feature=player_embedded). Until Cashill proves any one of his claims correct I don't see much reason to believe anything he says on the subject.

Comment: "A few other elements that should probably be considered." seems like an appendix, but that is the most important part of your answer. Consider rephrasing.